# Google Calendar API and G Suit accounts

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

We have a PHP calendar application that connects to google and syncs the events. We use Google Calendar API V3 and everything works perfect with private account, but is not working with G Suite accounts. We get 404 error when we submit the calendar ID (for a G Suite account). We had to create a service account on the main G Suite account and made public all the calendars to make it work, and it did work, but that is not viable solution for us... it's a company account and we cannot make public all the calendars.

Does anyone knows a solution on how to make this work ?

Thank you!

Comment: what does google support say about this?

Comment: google support points to stackoverflow

Comment: I might be wrong, but your problem sounds to me more like ACL issues. What type of authorization are you using? OAuth2? Is it using the credentials created using the G Suite account?

Comment: i'm using OAuth2 authentication, for each email address (calendar) we store the service_account_id, the certificate and the calendar_id: http://screencast.com/t/ylXnIc2qt

Comment: and with the service_account_id we just have to share it with the calendar that we want to sync: http://screencast.com/t/L5baQvVXsx .  And for the private account it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

There can be restrictions on the maximum visibility of G suite calendars outside the domain and I assume that is what you are hitting. Instead of making the G suite calendars public you can delegate the authority over the domain to your service account: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/domain